# Shuffle "coupled" elements in python array

Tags: python, arrays

Let's say I have this array:

```
np.arange(9)

[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

I would like to shuffle the elements with np.random.shuffle but certain numbers have to be in the original order.

I want that 0, 1, 2 have the original order.
I want that 3, 4, 5 have the original order.
And I want that 6, 7, 8 have the original order.

The number of elements in the array would be multiple of 3.

For example, some possible outputs would be:

```
[ 3 4 5 0 1 2 6 7 8]
[ 0 1 2 6 7 8 3 4 5]
```

But this one:

```
[2 1 0 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

Would not be valid because 0, 1, 2 are not in the original order

I think that maybe `zip()` could be useful here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's not a programming issue, you can add issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short solution using `numpy.random.shuffle` and `numpy.ndarray.flatten` functions:

```
arr = np.arange(9)
arr_reshaped = arr.reshape((3,3))   # reshaping the input array to size 3x3
np.random.shuffle(arr_reshaped)
result = arr_reshaped.flatten()

print(result)
```

One of possible random results:

```
[3 4 5 0 1 2 6 7 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Naive approach:

```
num_indices = len(array_to_shuffle) // 3 # use normal / in python 2
indices = np.arange(num_indices)
np.random.shuffle(indices)

shuffled_array = np.empty_like(array_to_shuffle)
cur_idx = 0
for idx in indices:
   shuffled_array[cur_idx:cur_idx+3] = array_to_shuffle[idx*3:(idx+1)*3]
   cur_idx += 3
```

Faster (and cleaner) option:

```
num_indices = len(array_to_shuffle) // 3 # use normal / in python 2
indices = np.arange(num_indices)
np.random.shuffle(indices)
tmp = array_to_shuffle.reshape([-1,3])
tmp = tmp[indices,:]
tmp.reshape([-1])
```